# MVC Linq to SQL Update Object in database

Tags: model-view-controller, linq-to-sql, repository

I have a table called Code in my LINQ to SQL datacontext.  I also have a class called Codes in my Models folder.  What I want to do is save the updated object Codes to my database table Code.  Is this possible?

In my controller, I would pass the edited Object to my Model.  My CodesRepository file contains this:

```
public Codes EditCode(Codes CodeToEdit)
        {
            private EventsDataContext _db = new EventsDataContext();
            Codes C = new Codes();
            C = CodeToEdit;

            _db.Codes.InsertOnSubmit(C); //error here, something about invalid arguments
             //InsertOnSubmit is for adding a new object, but I don't know the syntax
             // for editing an existing object.  

            _db.SubmitChanges();


        }
```

This is probably not the correct way of doing this so can someone point me in the right direction?  Do I even need a class called Codes or do I need to somehow just use my database table?  Thanks.

---

**Solution**:  I decided to change from Linq to SQL to an Entity Framework and it works much better.  This way, I don't have to define my Codes class since it comes straight from the database and I was able to delete the Codes class file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DataContext.Attach` when you get an object back that corresponds to en existing row in the database. For Linq-to-sql's optimistic concurrency handling to work this requires that you either have the original, unsaved object available, or that you have a `TimeStamp` column in the database. The latter is preferred, as it only requires one extra field to be handled (probably through a hidden field in the web form).

Comment: +1 for answering Linq To SQL and not Entity Framework! Cheers

Comment: I tried this: _db.Codes.Attach(CodeToEdit);  but i still get an error.    I don't think I can take an instance of my object Codes and save it to my Code database table.

Comment: There is some more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546187.aspx, which describes how to handle the attaching and optimistic concurrency.